# How to search javadoc recursively based on keyword?

Tags: javadoc

Is there a way to search through Javadoc for a certain keyword ? Is there a website that already does this for you ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with a standard way that does not involve a script.

There are doclets that can combine an entire library's worth of javadocs into one file, making it searchable, but of course you need the sources for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried http://www.kiwidoc.com/ ? Most of the common libraries are indexed and searchable.

> I am sad to announce that since early April 2012, kiwidoc as a service no longer exists. On the bright side, kiwidoc is now an [open source project](https://github.com/pongasoft/kiwidoc).

Comment: Seems to be closed as of April 2012

Answer (score 0):

This plug in for Firefox and Chrome is useful for quickly finding package and class names, though it's not a full text search: https://code.google.com/p/javadoc-search-frame/